# Extract Date and Time from Instagram Text in MS Excel

Tags: excel, timestamp

I'm want to extract date and time from a datetime stamp in excel  using formulas from data on Instagram text

The format is such:

2019-10-06T21:14:06.676169+00:00

I would like to have the date and time in separate columns preferably

The date in DDMMYY
The Time in HH:MM:SS

I have seen some answers for Python, but is there anything in excel that can get the job done for someone with no knowledge of Python?

Comment: What is your wanted result exactly? Differenct columns, a change of format etc? This is such a minimal post and even lacks your own attempt. Please have a look at [ask] a question with an [mcve] and edit your post accordingly.

Comment: Apologies I have edited the question

Comment: This works as desired!